# How to parse this JSON feed?

Tags: iphone, ios

I already posted this for a help , but unfortunately none of them worked for me ... 
 anyone is there to help me .. Please .....How to parse this JSON feed . I want to get all items like `'id','title','teaser','body','fid,'filename','filepath'` .........

```
{
    "data":{
        "mat_149":{
            "id":"149",
            "title":"The closing of 40% profit within 9 month",
            "teaser":"profit within 9 months only which is equal to 52% annual profit",
            "body":" The auction was presented in a very high and commercial lands.\u000d\u000a",
            "files":{
                "911":{
                    "fid":"911",
                    "filename":"22.JPG",
                    "filepath":"http://mysite/files/22_0.JPG"
                }
            }
        },
        "mat_147":{
            "id":"147",
            "title":"Company launches the city ",
            "teaser":"demands for distinguished lands.",
            "body":" The area size is quare meters This is evident through projects and many other projects.\u000d\u000a\u000d\u000a",
            "files":{
                "906":{
                    "fid":"906",
                    "filename":"2D7z.jpg",
                    "filepath":"http://mysite/dlr/files/2D7Z.jpg"
                }
            }
        },
        "mat_link":"mysite.com/"
    }
}
```

I'm parsing it like this with the json-framework:

```
NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] ;
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];  
NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary *) [parser objectWithString:response error:nil];  
NSLog(@"Data : %@", [data valueForKey:@"data"] );
```

I am getting Data:

```
NSLog(@"Data : %@", [data objectForKey:@"data"] );
```

I want to get all items `'id','title','teaser','body','fid,'filename','filepath'` ......... Please help me ...... Please .....

---

```
NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] ;
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];  
NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary *) [parser objectWithString:response error:nil]; 

NSDictionary *filedict = [data valueForKey:@"data"];
for(id key in filedict) 
{
    NSDictionary *files = [filedict valueForKey:key];
    NSLog(@"File -------------------  = %@",files);
}
```

But the problem is . sometimes its saying

```
File -------------------  = "<null>";
```

what i have to do .. help me ....

Comment: Could it be that sometimes the `files` field is empty ? :-) So what is there to fix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite easy, you receive a dictionary that contains (mainly) dictionary objects. You can see this by the notation of objects, e.g.:

**dictionary with string:**`"aKey":"aValue"` contains a string for the key 'aKey'.
  **dictionary with dictionary:**`"aDict":{"aKey":"aValue"}` is a dictionary with the name 'aDict' that contains 1 key called 'aKey'.

So if we keep this in mind, we can parse your JSON dictionary without much trouble.

```
NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary *) [parser objectWithString:response error:nil];
NSDictionary *dict = [data valueForKey:@"data"];
NSDictionary *mat = [dict valueForKey:@"mat_147"];
NSString *id = [mat valueForKey:@"id"];
NSString *title = [mat valueForKey:@"title"];
```

I guess `valueForKeyPath:` could be used as well to navigate the tree. For all the **mat_###** objects you might want to use an enumerator to traverse each **mat_###** dictionary.

Comment: thanks ... but if i have more items , what i should i do o get each mat_link items or  How to traverse through each dictionaries .... please.... for ' file ' can i use NSDictionary *files = [mat valueForKey:@"files"];

Comment: when i am using like this , i am getting the file ....      NSDictionary *mat = [dict valueForKey:@"mat_147"];         NSLog(@"Data : %@", mat );

Answer (score 3):

You can use this JSON parser https://github.com/stig/json-framework/
Then you will be able to use it like so:

```
NSDictionary *jsonData = [jsonString JSONValue];
//Get the data object
NSArray *data = (NSArray*)[jsonData objectForKey=@"**data**"];
```

now you can access data from the array object.

iterate through your data objects

```
for(int i=0;i<[data count];i++){
            NSDictionary *element = (NSDictionary *)[elements objectAtIndex:i];
  NSDictionary *user = (NSDictionary*)[element objectForKey:[[element allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]];
  NSString *ID = [user objectForKey:@"id"];
  NSString *title = [user objectForKey:@"title"];
  //...
}
```

**Note** that your object keys differ for everyobject in the element array ex. mat_157 vs. mat_156 so you can't get uniform key valued object. That's why you have to get the first key for every element like so:

```
NSDictionary *user = (NSDictionary*)[element objectForKey:[[element allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Comment: thanks , here i want to store the id, title, teaser , fid , filepath to some arrays . What i have to do ...........

Comment: @proCoder see my answer.  You data doesn't match your expectations.  You have some elements that are empty and therefore causing the null.  You need to enhance your processing of the elements to cater for these situations as your code assumes that every element has a files element when this is not true.

Answer (score 1):

Files is null in the last item in your data.

"mat_link":"mysite.com/"

There is no files element defined under this.